# sed/awk: Extract pattern from text stream

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

```
2011-07-01 ... /home/todd/logs/server_log_1.log ...
2011-07-02 ... /home/todd/logs/server_log_2.log ...
2011-07-03 ... /home/todd/logs/server_log_3.log ...
```

I have a file looks like the above. I want to extract the file names from it and output to STDOUT as:

```
server_log_1.log
server_log_2.log
server_log_3.log
```

Could someone help? Thanks!

The file name pattern is server_log_xxx.log, and it only occurs once in a line.

Comment: Since filenames can contain just about any character (spaces, newlines, control characters, on most unix filesystems, anything except `'\0'` and `'/'`), those 3 lines could be one valid filename.  There is no way to reliably recognize filenames unless you add some restrictions on the valid filenames and the stuff that can appear in the two `...`.  You especially want to be careful since logfiles that record unsanitized user-controlled variables (e.g. input, hostnames) can be targets for injection attacks against poorly written parsers.

Comment: jw013: nope, you need `'\n'` in the filename, otherwise those 3 lines are three entries

Comment: @yi `'\n'` is a valid character in filenames. You can't really do any sane matching on "all posssible filenames", and just as an example I pointed out that the entire line or any concatenation of lines (up to the file system's filename length limit) is a valid filename.  Now that Todd has specified the pattern he is looking for the problem becomes more reasonable (although the `xx` part is still unspecified, they are probably meant to stand for digits).  I don't really follow what you are saying "nope" to.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming the "xxx" placeholder is only digits:

```
grep -o 'server_log_[0-9]\+\.log'
```

Answer (score 9):

Pipe your file through following command:

```
sed 's/.*\(server_log_[0-9]\+\.log\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: sed 's/.*\(server_log_[0-9]\+\.log\).*/\1/' is more simpler, right?

Comment: Right, but with escaped braces. It didn't work for me before because I omitted `.*`. Updated my solution.

Comment: Doesn't this need -n arg and p suffix? sed -n 's/........./\1/p' is what works for me.

Answer (score 1):

With awk and your input pattern:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"}
     { print gensub(" .*$","","g",$5) }' INPUTFILE
```

See it action here: https://ideone.com/kcadh

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's|.*/\([^/ ]*\).*|\1|' infile
```

Comment: Add `p` to the end of the `s` command and add the `-n` option unless you want to see every line that doesn't match the pattern.