# use sed to extract a matching number

Tags: xml, sed, match

I have a xml file with a 1 line long string
I want to extract the number after ""
like the following example, I want to get 131

```
.....<yt:duration seconds='131'/>....
```

the "...." here means the substrings before and after "", which are long with different characters, numbers and marks.

how to use sed for extracting the matching number?
thanks

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938087/sed-awk-extract-pattern-from-text-stream) thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep`, not `sed`:

```bsh
grep -o "<yt:duration seconds='[0-9]\+'/>" file.txt | cut -f2 -d"'"
```

Answer (score 0):

A sed solution (using `@` as delimiter):

```
sed -r "s@.*<yt:duration seconds='([0-9]+)'/>.*@\1@" file.txt
```

For OSX, replace `-r` with `-E`